# Restore On Premises SSAS Database to Azure

Tags: azure, ssas, database-restore

I've set up an SSAS server on Azure and configured it to connect to an Azure storage account for backups.

Using the Azure Storage Explorer, I've also uploaded a backed-up SSAS database to this same storage account, and I'm trying to restore this backed up db to my SSAS server in Azure.

I've tried to do this using Powershell with

```
restore-asdatabase -restorefile "mySSASbackup.abf " -name "DBName" -server "asazure://southcentralus.asazure.windows.net/MySSASServer”
```

But then I get restore-asdatabase : This feature is not supported in AS Azure.

Trying via SSMS: I can connect to the server successfully, but when I try to restore a DB and click on the browse button I get an invalid UNC path notification.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Update: I've downloaded the latest version of SSMS and I could find the required abf file when clicking on "browse" when attempting to restore a db. When I process the restore, I get an invalid backup path (maximum 1024 characters" error though. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm more and more of the opinion that Azure Analysis Services is still in beta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607627/does-azure-analysis-services-support-service-principal-signon-to-sql-azure

Answer (score 1):

You may restore the .abf files into Azure Analysis Servive instance by uploading the file into associated blob storage of AS instance
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/backup-and-restore-your-azure-analysis-services-models/
https://www.neowin.net/news/azure-analysis-services-update-brings-backup-and-restore-new-pricing-options-and-more