# Look Up Activity in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to take oracle as the source dataset in the look up activity in azure data factory V2 ? I have an Oracle dataset 'DS_ORAC'. I would like to take this dataset as the Source Dataset in a look up activity.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you used a look up activity yet?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have used a look up activity. It is accepting Azure Sql Dataset as the Source Dataset but I can't find my 'DS_ORAC' dataset in the Look activity's Source Dataset's dropdown list.

Comment: Under "Supported Capabilities" here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity, Oracle is not listed.

Comment: So, there isn't any other ways I guess

Comment: That depends on what you're actually trying to do. What kind of source are you looking up against? Where is the final data going? How many rows in each source?

Comment: I'm looking to store the count of an Oracle table in a look up activity, whose value will then be used to update the 'SourceCount' column of the Audit table present in Azure Sql

Comment: I would always suggest simply loading the Oracle results into a staging table in SQL Azure then use T-SQL to assign those results wherever required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oracle dataset is now supported as well in Lookup Activity. We will soon update the Supported Capabilities at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity. You may take a try. The dataset and link service definition would be the same as Copy Activity.

Comment: The OP mentioned that the dataset was not in the dropdown list.

Comment: Right. So you are using Madrid App, correct? The UX change may still take several days. I will reply when it is ready.

Comment: I don't normally do this but since you seem to have an inside line on Azure... could I draw your attention to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607627/does-azure-analysis-services-support-service-principal-signon-to-sql-azure

Comment: Sorry, not close with AAS.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you have any contacts who are? No one anywhere has clarified what types of data source authentication it supports